# unable to recognize "kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, kubeadm

I am running K8s master(ubuntu 16.04) and node(ubuntu 16.04) on Hyper-V's Vm nor and able to join a node nor coredns pods are ready.

On k8s Worker Node:

admin1@POC-k8s-node1:~$ sudo kubeadm join 192.168.137.2:6443 --token s03usq.lrz343lolmrz00lf     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:5c6b88a78e7b303debda447fa6f7fb48e3746bedc07dc2a518fbc80d48f37ba4  --ignore-preflight-errors=all

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: this Docker version is not on the list of validated versions: 19.03.5. Latest validated version: 18.09
        [WARNING Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[kubelet-start] Downloading configuration for the kubelet from the "kubelet-config-1.16" ConfigMap in the kube-system namespace
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Activating the kubelet service
[kubelet-start] Waiting for the kubelet to perform the TLS Bootstrap...
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
error execution phase kubelet-start: error uploading crisocket: timed out waiting for the condition
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

admin1@POC-k8s-node1:~$ journalctl -u kubelet -f

```
Nov 21 05:28:15 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[55491]: E1121 05:28:15.784713   55491 reflector.go:123] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:459: Failed to list *v1.Node: Unauthorized
Nov 21 05:28:15 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[55491]: E1121 05:28:15.827982   55491 kubelet.go:2267] node "poc-k8s-node1" not found
Nov 21 05:28:15 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[55491]: E1121 05:28:15.928413   55491 kubelet.go:2267] node "poc-k8s-node1" not found
Nov 21 05:28:15 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[55491]: E1121 05:28:15.988489   55491 reflector.go:123] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to list *v1beta1.RuntimeClass: Unauthorized
Nov 21 05:28:16 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[55491]: E1121 05:28:16.029295   55491 kubelet.go:2267] node "poc-k8s-node1" not found
Nov 21 05:28:16 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[55491]: E1121 05:28:16.129571   55491 kubelet.go:2267] node "poc-k8s-node1" not found
Nov 21 05:28:16 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[55491]: E1121 05:28:16.187178   55491 reflector.go:123] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to list *v1beta1.CSIDriver: Unauthorized
Nov 21 05:28:16 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[55491]: E1121 05:28:16.230227   55491 kubelet.go:2267] node "poc-k8s-node1" not found
Nov 21 05:28:16 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[55491]: E1121 05:28:16.330777   55491 kubelet.go:2267] node "poc-k8s-node1" not found
Nov 21 05:28:16 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[55491]: E1121 05:28:16.386758   55491 reflector.go:123] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Unauthorized
Nov 21 05:28:16 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[55491]: E1121 05:28:16.431420   55491 kubelet.go:2267] node "poc-k8s-node1" not found
```

root@POC-k8s-node1:/home/admin1# journalctl -xe -f

```
Nov 21 06:30:45 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[75467]: E1121 06:30:45.670520   75467 reflector.go:123] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Unauthorized
Nov 21 06:30:45 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[75467]: E1121 06:30:45.691050   75467 kubelet.go:2267] node "poc-k8s-node1" not found
Nov 21 06:30:45 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[75467]: E1121 06:30:45.791249   75467 kubelet.go:2267] node "poc-k8s-node1" not found
Nov 21 06:30:45 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[75467]: E1121 06:30:45.866004
```

---

On K8s Master :
root@POC-k8s-master:~# kubeadm config images pull

```
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.16.3
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.16.3
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.16.3
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.16.3
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.3.15-0
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.2
root@POC-k8s-master:~# export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

root@POC-k8s-master:~# sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
```

root@POC-k8s-master:~# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
*****kube-system   coredns-5644d7b6d9-7xk42                 0/1     Pending   0          91s
kube-system   coredns-5644d7b6d9-mbrlx                 0/1     Pending   0          91s*****
kube-system   etcd-poc-k8s-master                      1/1     Running   0          51s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-poc-k8s-master            1/1     Running   0          32s
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-poc-k8s-master   1/1     Running   0          47s
kube-system   kube-proxy-xqb2d                         1/1     Running   0          91s
kube-system   kube-scheduler-poc-k8s-master            1/1     Running   0          38s
```

root@POC-k8s-master:~# kubectl apply -f

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flannel created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flannel created
serviceaccount/flannel created
configmap/kube-flannel-cfg created
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're using k8s version 1.16 and daemonset API group change to `apps/v1`

Update the link to this:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

And also there is an issue about this out there:
https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/16441

Comment: resolved master pending node issue but still node not able to join

Comment: Please check the flannel daemonset, Is it running on all nodes?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: `kubectl -n kube-system get daemonset kube-flannel-ds-amd64 -o wide`

Should run on all nodes.

Comment: root@POC-k8s-master:~# kubectl -n kube-system get daemonset kube-flannel-ds-amd64 -o wide
NAME                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE   CONTAINERS     IMAGES                                 SELECTOR
kube-flannel-ds-amd64   1         1         1       1            1           <none>          10m   kube-flannel   quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-amd64   app=flannel

Comment: root@POC-k8s-master:~# kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
poc-k8s-master   Ready    master   37m   v1.16.3   192.168.137.2   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS   4.4.0-62-generic   docker://19.3.5

Comment: How to add flannel daemonset on a node ?

Comment: You don't need to add explicitly a pod to the node because already you're using daemonset so that object apply a pod to all of the cluster nodes.

Comment: I so I guess it's failing in my case as I am not able to add a node to cluster using the join command as shown in my question above

Comment: Do you have any idea about my node join related issue? I have added kublet logs also to my question please check and help me plz

Comment: root@POC-k8s-node1:/home/admin1# journalctl -xe -f
Nov 21 06:30:45 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[75467]: E1121 06:30:45.670520   75467 reflector.go:123] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Unauthorized
Nov 21 06:30:45 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[75467]: E1121 06:30:45.691050   75467 kubelet.go:2267] node "poc-k8s-node1" not found
Nov 21 06:30:45 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[75467]: E1121 06:30:45.791249   75467 kubelet.go:2267] node "poc-k8s-node1" not found
Nov 21 06:30:45 POC-k8s-node1 kubelet[75467]: E1121 06:30:45.866004

Answer (score 1):

Resolved first part of the question by "#kubeadm reset" on the node and then join command worked! As  2nd part of the question was resolved first hence it was possible to resolve the question so @Alireza David thanks a lot.